# SQL performance for a returning stored procedure

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures

I have been asked the following question, what would you look into when you want to improve a stored procedure performance? The stored procedure is returning some value and have three joins in it. 
Other than making sure the joins are well written what one can do to make it perform better? This was a general question and no code was provided.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things you can do to optimize procedures, but it sounds like your SQL statement is pretty simple. Some things to watch out for:

- Inline functions. These can cause SQL to do a row by row evaluation and slow things down
- Data conversions on join statements. These can prevent indexes from being used.
- Make sure columns being joined on/in the where clause are indexed (for large data sets)

You can check out this website for more performance tips, but I think I covered most of what you need for simple statements:

[SQL Optimizations School](http://www.sqloptimizationsschool.com)

Comment: inline functions are different than cursors right? cursors are compiling row by row too. thanks for the website, it is a great source

Comment: Right, cursors are a way to loop through data. Inline functions are just ways to calculate data within your query. If you use functions to calculate data in a where clause and then compare that calculation to another value, good chance SQL won't be using indexes and it might have to do the calculation/comparison one row at a time instead of in mass.

Answer (score 2):

Check the indexes on the tables used in the joins.  Particularly, are the columns used in the joins indexed?

Example -

```
SELECT     *
FROM       SomeTable a
    JOIN   SomeOtherTable b on a.ItemId = b.ItemId
```

If these tables are large, indexing `ItemId` in both tables will typically help performance a lot.

You should do the same thing for any columns that are used in the `WHERE` clause, if your query has one.

```
WHERE  a.ProductId = @SomeVariableYouPassedToTheStoredProc
```

Indexing `ProductId` may help in this case.

Query performance is something you could go into a rabbit hole on, but this is a logical (and quick) place to start.

Comment: thanks for the index, other than that I can not think of anything in general, they are all query specific, like using tinyint instead of int and so on, aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it's a stored procedure has little to nothing to do with it. Optimise the sql inside.

As to how, all the usual suspects, including written by the sort of eejit who thinks you can guess what's wrong.

Copy the sql from the proc into a suitable tool, prefix it with Explain to see what's going on.

Comment: so it has nothing to do with the return values, right? you are talking about sql in the stored procedure itself.

Comment: Yep, well the sql inside it. Essentially all a stored procedure is, is a named and precompiled lump of sql with some trimmings for passing values in and out.

Answer (score 0):

I presume there are others options. For example: 
1. each of those joins could use restrict conditions which  looks like 'and permited_used_name = (select user_name from user_list where )'. The value could be derived once during procedure start (I mean the first string of procedure) to not overload the DB by many similar queries. 
2. starting from Oracle11 you could declare a function as function with cached results (i.e. function is calculated once and isn't recalculated each time when it is invoked) defining a set of tables which changes invalidate cache.

At any case the question is mostly DB-specific.

Comment: good to know about caching in Oracle11, can you refer me to a good example of it online?

Answer (score 0):

Run the Query Analyser on the SQL statement